# Can a Transformers be used for a classification problem?

Tags: python

I want to perform binary classification on a sequential data. I want to leverage the PyTorch nn.TransformerEncoder module, is there a way I can do this?
If not, are Transformers only used NLP?
If yes, how can I format the inputs and what tutorial can help me do this as quick as possible

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Look into some kaggle comps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transformers can be used for classification tasks. I found a good [tutorial where they used a BERT Transformer for the encoding and a Convolutional Neural Network for a sentiment analysis](https://databasecamp.de/en/use-case/bert-sentiment-analysis).

You can also fine-tune a whole Transformer for the classification but this is usually pretty intense when it comes to the training and you definitely need a GPU.